# Reading and tokenizing a file

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'm trying to read in a file and split up the characters using whitespace as a delimiter. I've managed to separate the input into a list of atoms, but I'm getting stuck trying piece it back together. This is my code so far:

```
tokenize_file(Name, Ret) :-
    open(Name, read, Str),
    read_file(Str, Ret),
    close(Str).

read_file(Stream,[]) :-
    at_end_of_stream(Stream).
read_file(Stream,[X|L]) :-
    \+ at_end_of_stream(Stream),
    get0(Stream, Char),
    write([X, Code]), nl,
    read_file(Stream,L).
```

This is generating an output that looks like this:

```
X = [i, n, t, ' ', a, d, d, ' ', '('|...]
```

What I can't seem to figure out is how to iterate through this list and concatenate each set of characters between whitespace into another list.
I've looked around but I'm struggling to understand how to manipulate lists in prolog.

Comment: You can parse a file with a grammar using  `library(pio)`. That would be much more efficient since it only has constant overhead (that is, independent of the size of the file), whereas your method requires space proportional to the file's size.

Comment: Instead of answering your own question in your question, you should add it as an answer. That is allowed on the site. Then you can accept your own answer, if you wish. Having it embedded in the question makes it harder for others to find.

Comment: Please re-post your solution as an answer, not an edit to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
tokenize_file(Name, Ret) :-
    open(Name, read, Str),
    read_file(Str, Lst),
    atomic_list_concat(Lst, '', AtmConcat),
    split_string(AtmConcat, " ", "", Ret),
    close(Str).
```

The atomic list concat recreates the input string (Could probably done more efficiently that reading in character by character, but it works). The split string then splits up the string by whitespace characters. Note that newline characters were actually marked up differently, so the rest of the code was also modified:

```
read_file(Stream,[X|L]) :-
    \+ at_end_of_stream(Stream),
    get0(Stream, Code),
    set_value(X, Code),
    read_file(Stream,L).

set_value(X, 10) :-
    char_code(X, 32).

set_value(X, Code) :-
    char_code(X, Code).
```

This replaces all newline characters with whitespace (ascii character 10 represents a newline)